# Android Drive API resourceID

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have saved the resourceId of all my files. Is there a way to get the driveId from this resourceId? I've tried this but nothing relevant:

HTTP request
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method that supports this in Drive API. Check the supported operations in [Android Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro).